# Redirect 301 in .htaccess with .htm doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

For a website I've made an .htaccess file with approximately 50 redirects. Unfortunately, most of them don't work. There seems to be a pattern:

**This works**

```
Redirect 301 /news/news http://levelav.nl/news/
```

**This doesn't work**

```
Redirect 301 /staff/staff.htm http://levelav.nl/people/
```

Before the redirects, I've placed the following code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Send other domains to www.levelav.nl
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !levelav.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.levelav.nl/$1 [L,R=301]

# Send other domains to levelav.nl
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !levelav.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://levelav.nl/$1 [L,R=301]

# Some WP rules
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Does anybody see or know what I'm doing wrong here?